# Query parameters not received from deep linking - react native(expo) and node js

Tags: node.js, react-native, deep-linking

I am using openAuthSessionAsync to do a call to my backend and sending the url for deep linking
I am redirected back successfully to my app but i don't get query parameters that i send from backend with deep link

My react native app side:

```
 const experiment = async()=>{
        try{
         let result = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(`http://myaddress :3901/api/testig?linkingUri=${Linking.createURL(
           "/?",
         )}`,);
         console.log(result)
        }catch(errr){
          console.log(errr)
        }
        
      }
```

My node js side:

```
router.get("/testig",(req,res)=>{


    url = req.query.linkingUri

**//url is exp://myaddress:19000/--/?**

    
    res.redirect(url+"?authToken=abc123")

})
```

I have also tried hard coding the url in backend but it only opens app back but with no parameters

And in my react native side in console i get this:

```
Object:{
"type":"dismiss",
}
```

UPDATE: Solved it by setting up eventListener for LINKING as follows

```
const handleDeepLink = (event)=>{
        let data = Linking.parse(event.url)
        setdata(data)
        if(JSON.parse(data.queryParams.isSuccessful) == true)
        {
          props.navigation.navigate("thankyou")
        }
      }
      React.useEffect(()=>{
        Linking.addEventListener("url",handleDeepLink)
        return(()=>{
          Linking.removeEventListener("url")
        })
      },[])
```

Answer (score 0):

use trycarch in the block to see errors and use `var url`

code lookslike

```
router.get("/testig",(req,res)=>{
    try {
        var url = req.query.linkingUri
        return res.redirect(url+"?authToken=abc123")
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
    }
})
```

Comment: Have solved it 
Going to update my question